# Is jsdom sending out possible ajax requests?

Tags: ajax, node.js, jsdom

I have been checking out [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) for parsing possible js code on html responses. The javascript could have hidden validation ajax requests that have to run like the following

```
var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp();
var rand = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
var url = "/path.php?validation_variable="+rand;
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200){
            response=xmlhttp.responseText.split(':')
            if(1 in response){
                var Exptime = new Date();
                Exptime.setTime(Exptime.getTime() + 86400000);
                document.cookie = 'pro_cc4='+response[1]+'; path=/; expires=' + Exptime.toUTCString();
            }
        }
    }       
}
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

I have a way of parsing requests like that but its complicated and prone to errors.